# C++ gotoxy out of console

Tags: c++, cursor

I have a small problem with using gotoxy().
I'd like to deny making posible scenario, where gotoxy() goes around console or to (-x,-y).

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
        getch();        
        COORD kursor;
        kursor.X = x;
        kursor.Y = y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), kursor);
    }
}
```

AND:

```
void chodzenie(){
koniec = false;
while( koniec == false ){
    unsigned char znak = getch();
    switch( znak )
    {
    case 0:
    case 224: //klawisze specjalne
        znak = getch();
        switch( znak )
        {
        case 72:            //strzałka w górę
                y--;
                gotoxy(x,y);
            break;
        case 80:            //strzałka w dół
                y++;
                gotoxy(x,y);
            break;
        case 75:            //strzałka w lewo
                x--;
                gotoxy(x,y);
            break;
        case 77:            //strzałka w prawo
                x++;
                gotoxy(x,y);
            break;
        }
        znak = 0;
        break;
    case 13: //ENTER
        break;
    case 27: //ESC
        koniec = true;
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Still, even if i have that if that checks if y and x are bigger than 0, my coursor might actually go to - let's say (-1,-6).

Comment: How do you know that? Why is this bad? How do you call `chodzenie`? And C++ isn't dynamically typed: `koniec = false;`.

Comment: You got it right. It does NOT, it just changes X and Y to miinus so if i want go back i'll have to make it  x>0 again. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How prevent invalid index

You use code such as:

```
    y--;   or  x++;
```

to compute the new cursor location.

You might sidestep the int operators and implement a small function to bump the value the direction you want, and limit the result. (to the edge or perhaps you would choose to wrap}

Consider this example for edge constraint:  (using TOP, BOTTOM as screen limits)

```
  void bmpY (int& y, int direction)
  { 
     y += direction;  

     // check bottom limit  (increasing Y moves down)
     if (direction > 0) { if (y > BOTTOM) y = BOTTOM; return; }

     if (direction < 0) { if (y < TOP)    y = TOP; return; }  

     // else direction == 0, do nothing
  }
```

and implement something similar for bmpX, LEFT, RIGHT

A similar simple arithmetic can handle the wrap choice.